# Can I install WINE as a desktop environment on Ubuntu to mimic Windows?

Tags: windows, ubuntu, wine, virtual-desktop

So I installed WINE on my machine and I think it would be cool to run it as a desktop environment on my device that would mimic the appearance **and** functionality of Windows by using windows' explorer.exe
Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run `winecfg`, then go to the *Graphics* tab and activate the option
`Emulate a virtual desktop`.

The details (like the background pic) can be set at `win.ini` file, in your `.wine` directory. 
You'll have to get that background pic from somewhere. It is not included in Wine, but it can be found at several places online.

This option is
[defined](https://wiki.winehq.org/Winecfg)
as:

> **Emulate a virtual desktop** -- With this setting enabled, created windows are confined to a single window (the "virtual" desktop window). You should select a desktop size smaller than what you run X in. Windows within a virtual desktop are not decorated or managed by your window manager.

The [FAQ](https://wiki.winehq.org/FAQ#How_do_I_get_Wine_to_launch_an_application_in_a_virtual_desktop.3F)
adds to this:

> **6.6.1 How do I get Wine to launch an application in a virtual desktop?**
>
> You can do this with winecfg. Add the application in the Applications
>   tab and then, in the Graphics tab, enable "Emulate a virtual desktop".
>
> You can also use the following command:
>
> ```
> wine explorer /desktop=name,1024x768 program.exe
> ```
>
> Replace program.exe with the name of your program, and change the
>   resolution to the size of the virtual desktop you want. Changing name
>   allows you to open several desktops simultaneously.

Comment: Okay, cool. Can I make a UNIX session so I can login to this?
(i have an original explorer.exe to work with, so that might help)

Comment: The virtual desktop is a graphical canvas on which are displayed the included Windows applications. It can be used in any graphical Linux session.